# Git. Как вернуть часть кода, удаленного в предыдущих commit?

Tags: git

Есть файл, в который я добавил 3 функции: function1..fucntion3. 
Каждая функция добавлялась своим commit.
Далее в файл была добавлена функция function4 и удалена функция function2.
Выполнен Commit и далее Push.
Таким образом, в файле сейчас есть функции function1, function3 и function4.

Теперь я решаю, что я зря удалил functon2 и ее надо вернуть.
Конечно, можно переключиться на commit, где она еще есть, скопировать ее, переключиться обратно на 4й commit,  вставить (да вообще любым способом добыть ее исходник) и закомитить 5й commit.
Но как такое сделать средствами самого git с помощью merge или еще как-то?
То есть чтобы не приходилось копировать руками (допустим реально удалена не одна функция, а 100500 в разных файлах).

Я пробовал откатывать master на commit3, где еще есть function2 и потом делать merge с origin/master (вернее я создавал еще branch но думаю это не важно). И с fast-forward и без. Но, как я понимаю, поскольку тут линейные изменения, git думает, что удаленная function2 в более позднем commit это ок и в итоге ее удаляет без конфликтов.

Как сделать чтобы merge (?) в итоге оставил все 4 функции в файле.
Для наглядности создал пример https://github.com/alezhu/test_delete_restore

Comment: Чтобы у вас такого не было, юзайте github или bitbucket. У github приватные репозитории платные (но они могут стать бесплатными, если вы студент), а у bitbucket приватные репозитории бесплатные. Тогда без труда будете визуально отслеживать свои коммиты.

Comment: @Colibri, и как Ваш совет поможет в данном случае? Причём тут эти сервисы? Автор, Вам нужен `git revert`.

Comment: @ixSci мой совет поможет избежать в дальнейшем подобных вопросов. Я не создавал ответ, я написал комментарий. Будьте сдержанней.

Comment: @Colibri, никак bitbucket & github тут не помогут. И от подобных вопросов не избавят.

Comment: @Colibri оба сервиса я юзаю. А для визуальности GitExtension. Каким образом это относится к вопросу?

Comment: @ixSci revert отменит мне комит и изменения в нем. это тоже не решает проблему. или я не умею его готовить. тогда можно поподробнее? в принципе нужный результат дает cherry pick - но там надо решать конфликт, типа "в это место в одном комите добавлена function2 а в этом - function3 и 4. где верно?" а мне надо автоматом чтобы оба изменения применились.

Comment: другого способа я не знаю и он вряд ли существует. Отменяете коммит, и редактируете то, что наотменяли. Потом комитите. У меня нет времени писать ответ, но уверен, Вам распишут по шагам, если сами не разберётесь.

Comment: можно, правда, еще с `git checkout` поиграться, но, на мой взгляд, `revert`  лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать сделать новую ветку где у вас function1, function3 и function4 , затем  cherry-pick забрать коммит добавления function 2  а затем сделать merge

Answer (score 1):

Должна помочь следующая команда:

```
git checkout <commit>
```

В случае если используется образец из примера (https://github.com/alezhu/test_delete_restore), то команда будет выглядеть

```
git checkout e94c812087977673a9a426e81db9b655b82e386c
```

На деле файлов может быть много, в таком случае изменения можно взять из конкретного файла:

```
git checkout <commit> -- <filename>
```